# Removing newline from path environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

When I look at my PATH environment variable, it appears to consist of a concatenation of two entries from my Registry.  One section of the path is found at:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment

and the other is found at:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment

The two sections are completely distinct -- there are no common entries between them.

My current path consists of the contents of the first entry, followed by a newline, followed by the contents of the second entry.

My question is - how do I get rid of that newline?

The problem I'm having is that there's a batch file that copies the %PATH% environment variable, and once it hits that newline, it assumes it's done reading, and further assumes the next thing after the newline (the first directory in the second PATH component) is the next command and tries to execute it, crashing out of the batch file.

The batch file isn't one I've written -- it's associated with the Anaconda environment manager, so I can't easily patch around it.

I may just copy the second part of the environment into the first so I can get on with my work, but I can't help thinking there's a better solution.

Comment: Those two registry locations are supposed to exist.  One belongs to the system and accessible by all users and the other belongs to the current user.  They are not supposed to be the same. Your conclusion they are concatenations of one another isn’t correct

Comment: I don’t think there should be a beeline there. Have you tried modifying the key that corresponds with each part of the path to see if you get the same results? Maybe there is something extra in the registry key that doesn’t belong there.